# LabVIEW: How to listen to property changed in .NET from LabVIEW

Tags: events, callback, listener, labview

I am writing a .NET library for LabVIEW to control our camera. I am not sure how to read property changed in .NET from LabVIEW.

For example, when we want to capture 10 images I want LabVIEW know when the 10th image is ready.  In the .NET library I have `Camera::Status` property and this property gets updated as the state of the camera gets updated.

I want to register an event handler on LabVIEW so that labVIEW can handle changes happening within .NET library.

I can't find how to register an event handler in LabVIEW. Please let me know if you know of any example.

Thanks,

Comment: maybe this can help: http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/2103952986B94F2F86257960004A3507 or this:https://forums.ni.com/t5/Developer-Center-Resources/Register-Callback-VIs-for-NET-Events-in-LabVIEW/ta-p/3523352. For more specific answers than general examples you would need to show what you did and where your specific problem lies.

Answer (score 0):

To register an event handler for a .NET event you use the [Register Event Callback Node](https://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361P-01/lvcomm/reg_event_callback/) located on the ActiveX palette.

There is also a min-howto in the LabView manual about [Registering and Handling .NET and ActiveX Events](https://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361P-01/lvhowto/reg_hndl_ax_evnts/).